# Application trying to use the wrong shared library

Tags: shared-library

I'm having a problem with a program (quartus) running on my ubuntu machine.  I'm getting the following error.

```
quartus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so: undefined symbol: XESetWireToEventCookie
```

I have the correct `libXi.so.6.0.0` file but no matter where I put it, the OS won't use it unless I `apt-get remove libxi-dev`, but a lot of software uses this `libXi`. What I want to do is add some sort of exception to the dynamic linker so that `quartus` uses the `libXi`.so that it needs and everything else still uses the one in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a shell script wrapper, as detailed [in this article](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), and make use of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` trick, so that you can launch your program and make sure that it is the only program to use the different shared library. **Do not** put it in your `.bashrc`, as you only want it to temporarily set the environmental variable. Launching your program with this shell script wrapper is probably the easiest way to deal with these sorts of issues to do with conflicting shared libraries.

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
/path/to/my/program
```

The second line of the script sets the library and the last line launches the program.

As noted [here](http://wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/how-to-correctly-use-ld_library_path), you can first run the above `export` line in terminal, and then run

```
ldd /path/to/my/program
```

to check that it is loading the correct libraries.

Comment: Ah yes, this makes sense and it would work except that the ldd tool doesn't recognize this as a dynamic executable.  I'm guessing here, but I think that somehow, the executable is using absolute pathing (or at the very least it isn't using LD_LIBRARY_PATH) because no matter what I set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to it always tries to use the shared object down in /home/local/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so . So what I did is write a horible script that replaces the symbolic link to libXi.so with a link to the correct library, runs the program, then replaces the link with the original again.